# Appending data to Pandas DataFrame with for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, spyder

I have a list of four URL's that I'm attempting to loop over and read into Pandas as a DataFrame. The problem is that it will only read in one of the .csv files.

The following is my code:

```
#Import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import time

#URL's for weekly projections on rotogrinders.com

url =['https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/nfl-qb.csv?site=draftkings',\
      'https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/nfl-rb.csv?site=draftkings',\
      'https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/nfl-wr.csv?site=draftkings',\
      'https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/nfl-te.csv?site=draftkings']

#Loop through each url, read the .csv into a DataFrame,append all together, 
#then write the DataFrame to a .csv file

file_name = 'weekly_projections_'
timestr = time.strftime('%Y%m%d')

df = pd.DataFrame()

for data in url:
    df = pd.read_csv(data)
    df.append
    df.to_csv(file_name + timestr + '.csv')
```

When I pass in . info() you can see i'm only getting 1/4 of the results. I would expect there to be 200+ entries

```
df.info

    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 28 entries, 0 to 27
Data columns (total 8 columns):
Baker Mayfield    28 non-null object
5400              28 non-null int64
CLE               28 non-null object
QB                28 non-null object
ATL               28 non-null object
30.18435          28 non-null float64
9.81225           28 non-null float64
18.69             28 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 1.8+ KB
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with your `for` loop:

Declare an empty dataframe at the beginning:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame()
for data in url:
    df = pd.read_csv(data)
    tmp = tmp.append(df)
    #df.to_csv(file_name + timestr + '.csv')

# Now, `tmp` will have dataframes for all URL's. You can then write this to `csv

tmp.to_csv(file_name + timestr + '.csv')
```

Let me know if this is what you want.